# C# Is there a way to "restart" a thread when a timer is triggered?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I want to make a program that contains 2 threads that are repeatedly invoked every time the timer is triggered.

I know you can't technically restart a thread, but I was wondering is there any work around to fix the problem?

```
using System; 
using System.Threading; 

public class Program { 

    // static method one 
    static void method1() 
    { 
        // some code here
    } 

    // static method two 
    static void method2() 
    { 
        // some code here
    } 

    // Main Method 
    public void Main() 
    { 
        // Creating and initializing timer
        System.Timers.Timer MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 4000;
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();
        autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        // Creating and initializing threads 
        Thread thr1 = new Thread(method1); 
        Thread thr2 = new Thread(method2);

        thr1.Start(); 
        thr2.Start(); 
    } 

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code below is wrong. I want to repeat/restart the threads
        thr1.Start(); 
        thr2.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Threads are like living things. Once they end they end. You have to specifically keep them alive if you want to reuse them. Do you specifically need to use the same threads?

Comment: What would you like to happen if at the time of the second `Tick` event, one or both threads are still running from the first `Tick` event?

Comment: It depends on scenarios. Do you want your tasks repeat? Or you assume your tasks are interrupted? If `Task` doesn't suit your use case, you may edit your post.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no...

Additionally, i would seriously consider using tasks instead of the `Thread` class.

However, if you really must use `Thread`, you can create it again then `Start` it

Option 2 (and probably less prone to problems), is put a *loop* in your *thread* and use something like an `AutoResetEvent` to fire that it should continue in the loop

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a "generic" answer, but the only solution I can think of is in your `timer1_Tick` function, destroy/stop the old threads and make new ones, which would look something like this:

```cs
// make sure the threads are stopped.
thr1.Stop();
thr2.Stop();

// make and start new threads.
thr1 = new Thread(method1); 
thr2 = new Thread(method2);
thr1.Start();
thr2.Start();
```

Comment: Although this is a legit answer its worth to note to future readers, **never abort a *thread***, its dangerous, a symptom of bad design, and should only be used in an emergency

Comment: The [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread) class doesn't contain a `Stop` method.